# value of type 1-dimensional array cannot be converted to string visual

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In this threat help me with the each row ( [Make a for each using SqlDataReader vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47226381/make-a-for-each-using-sqldatareader-vb-net/47227807?noredirect=1#comment81409334_47227807))

But when i wanna save the data ( on `GM.AsigDupla(Txtfecha.Text, cboPlanta0.SelectedValue, cboPlanta0.SelectedItem.Text, cboAlmacen.SelectedValue, cboAlmacen.SelectedItem.Text, mater, lot`)

the varibles od the arrarys mater and lot show the error : value of type 1-dimensional array cannot be converted to string

```
            Dim mater() As String
            Dim planta() As String
            Dim almacen() As String
            Dim lot() As String
            Dim cantidad() As String
            Dim cantadiat() As String
            Dim undad() As String
            Dim Cantidadc() As String
            Dim CantidadB() As String
            Dim Session1() As String
            Dim fecha() As String
            Dim RowCounter As Integer = 0
            RowCounter.ToString()




            Dim Con34 As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
            Con34.ConnectionString = C.GetAppConfiguracion("Inventario", "ConnInventario")
            'Dim editCustQuery As String = "select Idmaterial , IdLote from s_RptInventarioSAP where idPlanta = '" & cboPlanta0.SelectedValue & "' and IdAlmacen = '" & cboAlmacen.SelectedValue & "'"
            Dim editCustQuery As String = "select * from dbo.s_RptInventarioSAP"
            Con34.Open()
            Dim CustCommand As New SqlCommand(editCustQuery, Con34)
            Dim sqladapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(CustCommand)
            Dim tableresult As New DataTable(editCustQuery)

            sqladapter.Fill(tableresult)
            Con34.Close()
            For Each TableRow As DataRow In tableresult.Rows
                mater = tableresult.Rows.Item(RowCounter).Item(0)
                planta = tableresult.Rows.Item(RowCounter).Item(1)
                almacen = tableresult.Rows.Item(RowCounter).Item(2)
                lot = tableresult.Rows.Item(RowCounter).Item(3)
                cantidad = tableresult.Rows.Item(RowCounter).Item(4)
                cantadiat = tableresult.Rows.Item(RowCounter).Item(5)
                undad = tableresult.Rows.Item(RowCounter).Item(6)
                Cantidadc = tableresult.Rows.Item(RowCounter).Item(7)
                CantidadB = tableresult.Rows.Item(RowCounter).Item(8)
                Session1 = tableresult.Rows.Item(RowCounter).Item(9)
                fecha = tableresult.Rows.Item(RowCounter).Item(10)



                RowCounter = RowCounter + 1
            Next

            Dim resultado As String
            resultado = GM.AsigDupla(Txtfecha.Text, cboPlanta0.SelectedValue, cboPlanta0.SelectedItem.Text, cboAlmacen.SelectedValue, cboAlmacen.SelectedItem.Text, mater, lot)
            'i = i + 1
            With lbError0
                .Visible = True
                .Text = resultado
            End With


        Catch ex As Exception
            lbError0.Text = ex.Message

        End Try

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I see a couple errors.

```
        Dim mater() As String
        Dim planta() As String
        Dim almacen() As String
        Dim lot() As String
        Dim cantidad() As String
        Dim cantadiat() As String
        Dim undad() As String
        Dim Cantidadc() As String
        Dim CantidadB() As String
        Dim Session1() As String
        Dim fecha() As String
        Dim resultado() As String
        Dim RowCounter As Integer = 0




        Dim Con34 As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        Con34.ConnectionString = C.GetAppConfiguracion("Inventario", "ConnInventario")
        'Dim editCustQuery As String = "select Idmaterial , IdLote from s_RptInventarioSAP where idPlanta = '" & cboPlanta0.SelectedValue & "' and IdAlmacen = '" & cboAlmacen.SelectedValue & "'"
        Dim editCustQuery As String = "select * from dbo.s_RptInventarioSAP"
        Con34.Open()
        Dim CustCommand As New SqlCommand(editCustQuery, Con34)
        Dim sqladapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(CustCommand)
        Dim tableresult As New DataTable(editCustQuery)

        sqladapter.Fill(tableresult)
        Con34.Close()
        For Each TableRow As DataRow In tableresult.Rows
            mater(RowCounter) = tableresult.Rows.Item(RowCounter).Item(0).toString
            planta(RowCounter) = tableresult.Rows.Item(RowCounter).Item(1).toString
            almacen(RowCounter) = tableresult.Rows.Item(RowCounter).Item(2).toString
            lot(RowCounter) = tableresult.Rows.Item(RowCounter).Item(3).toString
            cantidad(RowCounter) = tableresult.Rows.Item(RowCounter).Item(4).toString
            cantadiat(RowCounter) = tableresult.Rows.Item(RowCounter).Item(5).toString
            undad(RowCounter) = tableresult.Rows.Item(RowCounter).Item(6).toString
            Cantidadc(RowCounter) = tableresult.Rows.Item(RowCounter).Item(7).toString
            CantidadB(RowCounter) = tableresult.Rows.Item(RowCounter).Item(8).toString
            Session1(RowCounter) = tableresult.Rows.Item(RowCounter).Item(9).toString
            fecha(RowCounter) = tableresult.Rows.Item(RowCounter).Item(10).toString

            resultado(RowCounter) = GM.AsigDupla(Txtfecha.Text, cboPlanta0.SelectedValue, cboPlanta0.SelectedItem.Text, cboAlmacen.SelectedValue, cboAlmacen.SelectedItem.Text, mater(RowCounter), lot(RowCounter))

            RowCounter = RowCounter + 1
        Next



        'i = i + 1
        With lbError0
            .Visible = True
            .Text = resultado
        End With


    Catch ex As Exception
        lbError0.Text = ex.Message

    End Try

End If
```

End Sub

Ok this should work but there is something I don't understand you are displaying the result in a textbox I presume. but here is the trick.  As I answer on the previous thread, the variable mater and lot are arrays, you can not call mater or lot directly.  You have to specify what item of the array.   With the modifications I did, resultado is another array so you can not call it directly you have to specify the item resultado().

I need more information what you will do with resultado.

Comment: resultado return a text for the metod for insert Insdupla, thar said it was asaved or not with the label lberror0

Comment: i try with your fixed but in wit lberro0 .text = resultado i got tha sema error

Comment: resultado is now an array with my code so you have to call it lberro0.text=resultado(#) replace the # for the row number of the table that you need.

Also make some tests, use resultado(0), resultado(5) etc so you will see the difference.

(Veo que hablas español, con el codigo que puse, vas a tener muchos resultados, uno por cada fila en la tabla) Translation of the parentesis: I see you speak spanish, with the code i wrote you are going to get as many resultados as there are rows in the table.

I see that you are confused with the term Array, google it so you can understand the code.

Comment: yeah i speka spanish, i will keep try, thanks a lot for your help and time :D

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each TableRow3 In tableresult3.Rows

                        mater3 = tableresult3.Rows.Item(RowCounter3).Item(0).ToString
                        lote3 = tableresult3.Rows.Item(RowCounter3).Item(1).ToString


                        Dim Con5 As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
                        Dim StrSQL4 As String

                    Con5.ConnectionString = C.GetAppConfiguracion("Inventario", "ConnInventario")

                    StrSQL4 = "EXEC P_AsigDupla2 '" & Txtfecha.Text & "', '" & cboPlanta0.SelectedValue & "', '" & cboPlanta0.SelectedItem.Text & "', '" & cboAlmacen.SelectedValue & "', '" & cboAlmacen.SelectedItem.Text & "', '" & mater3 & "', '" & lote3 & "', '" & tbDupla.Text.ToUpper & "','" & estatus & "'"
                    Con5.Open()
                    Dim CmdAd As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(StrSQL4, Con5)
                    CmdAd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                    Con5.Close()
                    RowCounter3 = RowCounter3 + 1
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the 
code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.